# difference between Label classes

Tags: asp.net, controls, label

What is the difference between

```
system.windows.forms.label
```

and

```
system.web.ui.webcontrols.label controls
```

if at all? In what context would we use one or the other?

Comment: Your question is basic, but perfectly valid. I've edited it for clarity.

Comment: @Tim Then why down vote?  I was not able to understand the difference from the msdn library as it suggested that both are used for displaying text on a form. So i thought posting the question would clear out the air of ambiguity in my mind. I didn't get Druid's explanation any where in my google search. And I think this question is basic but not repetitive or frivolous. I just started programming in asp.net so my questions are rather basic as compared to many of the questions posted in this forum. I think it would be a discouragement for learners to ask  by down voting basic questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as the inheritance suggests, you would use the `System.Windows.Forms.Label` in a Windows Forms application.

In ASP.NET, you have a choice between using `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label` and `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal`. [Here is a good explanation](http://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/archive/2011/03/23/label-vs-literal-in-asp-net.aspx) on the difference between `Label` and `Literal`.

Answer (score 2):

`system.windows.forms.label` is used when you develop a desktop application and other while developing a web application

Answer (score 2):

**system.windows.forms.label** : Represents a standard Windows label and used in desktop applications.

**system.web.ui.webcontrols.label** : Represents a label control, which displays text on a Web page and used in web application.